# Strange Mongoose error using Passport login strategy (LinkedIn) - object has no method 'replace'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

Here's my error message, not very helpful in terms of letting me know where in my code it happens - at first I thought it was in my Passport strategy code below, but that's not the case:

```
[TypeError: Object function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    } has no method 'replace']
TypeError: Object function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    } has no method 'replace'
    at ValidatorError.MongooseError.formatMessage (c:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\node_sports_lineup\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error.js:22:16)
    at new ValidatorError (c:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\node_sports_lineup\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:20:24)
    at validate (c:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\node_sports_lineup\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:608:22)
    at c:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\node_sports_lineup\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:618:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (c:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\node_sports_lineup\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:612:21)
    at c:\Users\denman\WebstormProjects\node_sports_lineup\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:967:15
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

when I run this code, I do NOT get an error, the change in the code is that I am searching for two other parameters in my

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
        consumerKey: LINKEDIN_API_KEY,
        consumerSecret: LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY,
        callbackURL: "/auth/linkedin/callback"
    },
    function (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

        UserModel.getNewUser(app.system_db()).findOrCreate({linkedin_id: profile.id}, function (err, user) {
            if(err){
                 console.log(err);
            }
            return done(err, user);
        });

    }
));
```

however when I run this code, I do get an error:

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
        consumerKey: LINKEDIN_API_KEY,
        consumerSecret: LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY,
        callbackURL: "/auth/linkedin/callback"
    },
    function (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        UserModel.getNewUser(app.system_db()).findOrCreate({username:String(profile.id), password:String(profile.id), linkedin_id: profile.id}, function (err, user) {
            if(err){
                 console.log(err);
            }
            return done(err, user);
        });

    }
));
```

I want to thank Node.js and dynamic typing for the privilege to experience this error.
At this point, I believe it's because the findOrCreate method wants only one field in the object passed to it. Doesn't make much sense, but that's my best guess.

Here is Mongoose schema for User

```
exports.registerSchema = function (mongoose,findOrCreate) {

    userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            type: String
            //isUnique: true
            //required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String
            //required: true
        },
        teamSnap: {
            username: String,
            password: String,
            teamSnapToken: String
        },
        linkedin_id: {
            type: String
        },
        email: {
            type: String
            //required: true
        },
        numberOfLineupsCreated: Number,
        hasPaidAlready: Boolean,
        about: String,
        phone: String,
        gender: String,
        address: String,
        latitude: Number,
        longitude: Number,
        registered_at: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        created_at: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        updated_at: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    });

    userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);
   userSchema.path('username').validate(/^[a-z]+$/i, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    userSchema.methods.validPassword = function (pwd) {
        return (this.password === pwd);
    };

};
```

Comment: Try change `String(profile.id)` to simply `profile.id`

Comment: unfortunately that's not the problem

Comment: You're clearly leaving something out. Could you update the question with the Mongooose Schema too?

Comment: maybe I should get rid of the validate methods. if that's the case, the error message simply blows.

Comment: The validate method is trying to validate the username field, but for some reason the username field is an object, which is why you're getting this error.

Comment: If you `console.log(profile.id);` what is the output?

Comment: Profile.id is all good, I had several problems with this whole setup, but the final problem was the validation on username / password fields in the Mongoose schemamodel object

Comment: thanks for your help anyway, I should delete this question, will wait a day or two to make sure